# Safari translates all languages... except Korean?

Tags: macos, safari, internationalization, language

Safari on macOS offers page translations for nearly any language I throw at it. Chinese, Japanese, Spanish, French.

But not Korean.

This behavior is strange. On iOS 16, Safari will translate Korean pages inherently. This is without the need for Microsoft Translator to be installed.

And system-wide translation on macOS works fine for Korean. I can highlight any text in any app, and by context-menu the standard Apple translation menu will pop-up and function. Literally the only thing that *doesn't* work is site translation, in macOS, in Safari, for Korean.

- I thought perhaps me being physically located in Korea was related. But VPNs return the same result. Same for a friend in physically in USA. Korean is never translated.
- I thought maybe my language settings were to blame. But having Korean in the "Preferred Languages" dialog, -- or having it removed--, has no effect.
- I thought the web pages itself were wrongly encoded. But I've tried at least 50 different Korean websites, checking many examples of HTML lang tags. No variety triggers Safari translations.
- I thought my region settings might be to blame. Set it to USA, set it to Korea, all the same: no offered translation.

I can't figure out what's going on. Why does Apple seem to support Korean translation for macOS system-wide translation, for iOS full site translation, and every other language for translation, except Korean, and only in this particular usage?

I'm open to any suggestions or tips. I already have Chrome and Whale installed, and do use them for auto-translations. No problems there. It'd just be nice to be able to use Safari.

To verify, here are some sample Korean sites, none of which Safari (desktop) will ever offer to translate, or can translate:

- https://www.ytn.co.kr/_ln/0101_202210281706202037
- https://www.chosun.com/politics/politics_general/2022/10/28/23ZQBTHSORDDHDAEZXGXFBIINI/
- https://imnews.imbc.com/news/2022/politics/article/6421564_35666.html
- https://gall.dcinside.com/board/view/?id=dcbest&no=88122

Comment: What version of MacOS are you using?

Comment: @TomGewecke Monterey, 12.6

Comment: FYI- it got automatically solved when I upgraded to Ventura. Go figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say why, but upgrading to Ventura solved the problem. Now all those same example websites gets a Translation request from Safari.